# Refresh the deployed HTML web page using Google Apps Script

Tags: html, google-apps-script

I have created a small website using HTML service of Google apps script. 
Here is GAS Code

```js
function doGet() {
   var t = HtmlService.createTemplateFromFile('form');
  t.email=Session.getActiveUser().getEmail();
   return t.evaluate().setSandboxMode(HtmlService.SandboxMode.IFRAME);
}
```

and this is HTML Code

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
   <head>
   <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">
     <base target="_top">  
   </head>
   
    <body onLoad="addEventListeners()">
    <div class="container-fluid">
   <form id="form1"> 
     <label for="comp_indiv_name" id="company_individual_name" style="display: block" >2. COMPANY NAME</label>
      <input type="text" class="form-control" name="cName" required>
  <br>
   <input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" value="Create Contract Now">
   </form>
   </div>
   
  
    
<script>
function addEventListeners() {
var condition=true;

document.getElementById('form1').addEventListener('submit', function(e){
e.preventDefault();
if(condition==true){condition=false;google.script.run.addData(this);}});

}
</script>
</body>

</html>
```

HTML page has one form with just one question, and when that form is submitted, the value get written in spreadsheet. Code for that is

```js
function addData(form)
{
  var ss=SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheet=ss.getSheetByName('test');
  sheet.getRange(5,5).setValue(form.cName)
  htmlPage();
}
```

All i want is once the value gets written on the sheet, this HTML page gets refreshed automatically. Right now it just stays as it is. Link to the HTML page is https://script.google.com/macros/s/AKfycbzavm6TPFOkIXj_V0uD8XIqMN-9w6jAgp_QgRkJXawFJF59rPU/exec

Comment: Simply return something from your addData() function- for example the new HTML content of the page and use it in an "onSuccess"  client JavaScript function to update the page.

Comment: I just tested your app, still a lot of work to do on it, use client JavaScript to modify the page once the question had been answered, disabling the button would be a good idea too! This is typically what onSuccess() handler is made for. I cannot give you the link here but it's easy to find in Google'd documentation (I'm on cellphone right now)

Comment: Thank you Serges. I have disabled the button if(condition==true){condition=false;google.script.run.addData(this);} I called the a function that returns the same page (clone of doGet() function), but no luc)

Comment: Search for the doc about success handler and read the examples. This has to happen in the HTML script part.

Answer (score 1):

If you truly want to refresh the page, and not just clear the input field, then I would add a hidden link that has your web app URL, and then programatically "click" it when the server code has completed.

### HTML

```
</form>

   <a id="linkToThisWebApp" href="https://script.google.com/macros/s/webAppID/exec" style="display:none">Hidden</a>
   <!-- <button onclick="reloadPg()">Test</button> -->
   </div>
```

### Script tag - Code with success handler

```
<script>
function addEventListeners() {
var condition=true;

document.getElementById('form1')
  .addEventListener('submit',
  function(e){
    e.preventDefault();

    if(condition==true){
      condition=false;
      google.script.run
        .withSuccessHander(reloadPg)
        .addData(this);
    }


  });

}

window.reloadPg = function() {//Runs when server code has completed
  console.log('reloadPg ran');
  document.getElementById('linkToThisWebApp').click();//Click the link
}
</script>
```